# Check what data type the next line of a file is in java without moving the current scanner position

Tags: java, string, netbeans, input, java.util.scanner

I have a input txt file as follows:

```
int int String String
int int String
int int String
int int String String 
int int String
...
```

There will always be 2 ints followed by either 1 or 2 strings. The problem is, I don't know when there will be 2 strings or when there will be 1.

How would I check if there is a 2nd string after the 1st string (and if so, scan it into the variable string2, and I will append string2 to the end of string1 after)

The solution I thought of is something along the lines of

```
after String1 is scanned:
if nextline == String, then scan it into string2, start scanning loop over
if nextline != String, start scanning loop over
```

But I don't know how to code this in java

Comment: In a file, *everything* is a String. What if my String was "145", which would you do?

Comment: Well, I am using textfile.nextInt() to scan in my ints

Answer (score 0):

you can read line per line, split it on *whitespace* and check the length of the array. if the length is 4 then second string is exist

```
String  line= null;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader("yourfile.txt");
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] arr = line.split("\\s+");
    if(arr.length == 4){
        //second string is exist
    }
    ....
 }
```

Comment: there will always be 2 ints, but either 1 or 2 strings, so at most the length will be 4, and at least the length will be 3